# Issue using AWS CLI s3 sync with a particular directory on MacOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, amazon-s3

I am creating a small job to keep my macs configuration synced. It uses the AWS s3 sync to keep the configuration files on both computers.

The thing is that the `Library` directory keeps getting copied, even when I explicitly tell aws cli to ignore it.

What I tried:

```
    --exclude "*" \
    --include ".aws/*" \
    --include ".awsume/*" \
    --include ".ssh/*" \
    --include ".kube/*" \
    --include ".oh-my-zsh/*" \
    --include ".vscode/*" \
    --include "Projects/*" \
    --include ".zprofile" \
    --include ".zsh_history" \
    --include ".zsh_sessions/*" \
    --include "zshrc"
```

And

```
   aws s3 sync . s3://my_bucket \
    --exclude "Library/*" \
    --exclude "Library" \
    --exclude "/home/user/Library/*"
```

Comment: Which `Library` directory is being copied? There are several different Library directories on a Mac.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The main Library directory in a user's home directory –

Comment: The problem is probably that `/home/user/Library/*` does not include their _actual_ path -- I presume that `user` would need to be replaced with their username.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the command that is working, navigate to the folder and run the following

```bash
aws s3 sync . s3://my_bucket/ --exclude "*Library/*"
```